# Waiting until for loop iteration to be completed visually before going onto next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, iteration

```
function start_map_one() {

for (var i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
      $.when(update_map()).then(evolve('W','W1',18,2,sea_limitations,20,350));
}
}
```

here, update_map() updates a div. However instead of the div updating visually 15 times in sequence, it appears to wait until all 15 iterations are complete and then display the finished div.

So im looking for this order ideally:

update_map() map information is used to update the div - user
    sees the visual result... then...

evolve() map information
    updated behind the scenes

update_map() map information is used to update the div - user
    sees the visual result... then...

evolve() map information
    updated behind the scenes

etc etc 15 times

Comment: what is the value returned by `update_map()`

Comment: How long does `update_map()` and `evolve()` take?  If you don't have something delaying one of those functions.  It could be that you are updating the `div` too fast.

Comment: @Eclecticist update runs through an array of over 1000 objects and adds div's to the main div depending on the object information. Evolve goes through each object in the array and does probably a few dozen operations/checks. So im pretty sure its not so that fast. When I remove the loop so I can click each iteration manually its approx 0.3-4 seconds per iteration.

Comment: As a side note, keep in mind that JavaScript is single-threaded.  Sometimes you can get odd behavior while reflowing the document in a loop because of that.  I suggest using a `setTimeout` with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using recursion for this. Without knowing too much about what the code does, it could look something like this...

```
function start_map_one() {
    start_map_one_helper(15);
}

function start_map_one_helper(count) {
    if (count <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    $.when(update_map()).then(function () {
        evolve('W','W1',18,2,sea_limitations,20,350);
        start_map_one_helper(count - 1);
    });
}
```

Note that the `then()` callback needs to be wrapped in a function, otherwise it executes right away.

You may need to wrap the recursive call in a setTimeout to see the changes on the screen...

```
function start_map_one() {
    start_map_one_helper(15);
}

function start_map_one_helper(count) {
    if (count <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    $.when(update_map()).then(function () {
        evolve('W','W1',18,2,sea_limitations,20,350);
        setTimeout(function() {
            start_map_one_helper(count - 1);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much. There was an extra ')'  on the evolve() line I had to delete.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Corrected the answer. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't give the browser enough time to change the display. Just add a delay in between the execution of each iteration. Try this solution

```
function start_map_one() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.when(update_map()).then(evolve('W','W1',18,2,sea_limitations,20,350));
        }, i * 100);
    }
}
```

Change the 100 to a time suitable for you.

Also, you're not encapsulating the evolve function (Which means you're calling evolve during the loop instead of calling it through then. Simply wrap it in a function.